# Trying to align text next to the top right corner of an image in HTML, invalid character in attribute name

Tags: html

I'm working on a school project, and I need to code a site. I'm trying to make my site a bit "blog-styled", and I'm having a problem when it comes to starting text next to the top-right corner of an image.  Aligning to the right only made it so the text started at the lower-right corner. I tried using td-align and vertical align, though that only moved my image directly to the right of my text, giving me an error that says "invalid character in attribute name".

Could anyone help me out with this? The project is due in about a week.
Here's the faulty code.

```
<p> 
  <img src="Webp.net-resizeimage.jpg" <td align="right" style="vertical-align: top;" /> 
</p>
```

Comment: Try putting the vertical align on the image instead of the td. See if that helps.

Comment: Can you please provide your current html? We'll need more details before we can provide any recommendations. Also, have you had a look at CSS? https://github.com/DecodeMTL/html-css-101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

For starters, your code snippet (which next time please include directly in your post instead of as an image with something like the snippet editor) is syntactically and semantically very incorrect (copying/pasting random stuff into something and hoping it will work does you no favors in learning). It's your first post but in the future you might try a little more effort at least on your part since there's numerous tutorials for this sort of thing on the net. However let's give you a freebie and try a different approach to put you on a better track, cheers;

```css
figure {
  position: relative;
  border: gray 1px solid;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  height: 15rem;
  width: 15rem;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVW9D.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}

figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: red;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: .25rem 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.85);
  border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <figcaption>Words Words Words</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow Oktoroc,  place the image in the background of the paragraph then align the text to the right but I am unsure if this is you desired outcome.

```css
p {
    background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/250');
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<p>Background Example</p>
```